# Is there a group containing two subgroups: H with 6 elements and K with 10, such that $|H\cap K| = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a group containing two subgroups: H with 6 elements and K with 10, such that $|H\cap K| = 1$?

I thought of this question when I noticed that $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ contains such two subgroups indeed, but $|H\cap K| = 2$ in this case. My guess is that it is not possible, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Why did you try $30$ and not $60$?

Comment: $60$ is the same case more or less, isn't it?

Comment: How about $ℤ/6ℤ × ℤ/10ℤ$? Did you mean “Is there a group containing *exactly* two *non-trivial, proper* subgroups with …”? In this case, the answer is No.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ means. Non-trivial? Of course, trivial groups only contain the neutral element, right? If it's impossible, do you of a way to prove it?

Comment: It’s $ℤ_6$. Take $ℤ_6 × ℤ_{10}$.

Comment: That looks correct to me. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you will not find a cyclic group with this property because a cyclic group has a unique subgroup of each order and both $H$ and $K$ would have to contain the unique subgroup of order $2$. The intersection would therefore be non-trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $ℤ_6 × ℤ_{10}$ take $H = ℤ_6 × 0$ and $K = 0 × ℤ_{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
G &=& \langle a,b \mid a^6=b^{10}=aba^{-1}b^{-1}=e \rangle \\
H&=&\langle a \rangle \\
K&=& \langle b \rangle
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I downvoted this: That is just a waaay to complicated formulation for such a question. (Also, $H = ⟨a⟩$ not $\{a\}$ unless you use very different notation. Same for $K$.)

Comment: Not saying this is wrong, but what guarantees me that for example $a^3 \neq b^2$?

Comment: If $a^3=b^2$ it would have said so in the definition of $G$.

Comment: But than you have to prove an existence of such a structure, right? I can't see why I should believe it exists.

Comment: It is reasonably easy to see that the group $G$ consists of elements of the form $a^ib^j$ $i=0,\cdots,5$ and $j=0,1,\cdots,9$.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton The group $G$ is (maybe even by defintion) a group $G$ generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ such that for any other group $G'$ with elements $α$ and $β$ subject to the relations $α^6 = β^{10} = αβα^{-1}β^{-1}$ there is exactly one group homomorphism $G → G'$ with $a ↦ α$ and $b ↦ β$. It therefore suffices to find any other group $G'$ with these relations such that $α^3 ≠ β^2$. Take $α = β = -1$ in $G' = \{\pm 1\}$ for example. The easiest way that *I* see that $H ∩ K = 1$ is by establishing $G \cong ℤ_6 × ℤ_{10}$ this way (I guess). That’s in large part why I downvoted.

Comment: @k.stm Note that if there is an abelian group which satisfies the conditions it will contain a subgroup with this presentation.

Comment: @MarkBennet Okay, granted – but what does this tell us?

Comment: @k.stm Some of us learn group presentations for basic cases (cyclic and dihedral groups for example) before structure things like direct products.

Comment: @MarkBennet Okay, I removed the downvote. Still, the answer misses that $\# H = 6$, that $\# K = 10$ and why $H ∩ K = 1$ – or rather leaves it as being obvious. Is there a nice / elementary way to see the latter *without* using direct products and the universal property of group presentations? (Question not directed at you specifically, Mark.)

Comment: @k.stm I take your point too. Group presentations are tricky things. If the presentation just had $a^6=b^{10}=1$ that would be an infinite group

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate a non-abelian group with this property, consider $G$ being the symmetric group on $5$ elements.

Let $H$ be the symmetric group on the first three elements, which has order $6$. The elements of order $2$ are odd permutations.

Let $K$ be the dihedral group of order $10$ generated by $a=(1 2 3 4 5)$ and $b=(2 5)(3 4)$ so that $b^5=a^2=1$ and $b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}$. All of these permutations are even.